Can't delete an user session from Prisma database in a Node.js back-end through a react front-end
I have a back-end function to logout and delete session in Prisma database.
const logout = (req, res, next) => {
  req.logout((err) => {
    if (err) {
      return next(err);
    }
    req.session.destroy((err) => {
      if (err) {
        return next(err);
      }
      res.clearCookie("connect.sid");
      return res.status(200).json({ message: "Logout sucessfully" });
    });
  });
};


It is used in the route:
router.post("/session/logout", sessionController.logout);

When I call it in my front-end using this function:
const logout = async () => {
        try {
            console.log(API_URL)
            console.log("Starting logout...");
            await fetch(`${API_URL}/session/logout`, {
                method: 'POST',
                credentials: 'include',
            });
            console.log("Logged out from server.");
            localStorage.removeItem('token');
            localStorage.removeItem('user');
            setIsLoggedIn(false);
            setUser(null);
            console.log("Client-side logout successful.");
        } catch (error) {
            console.error("Logout failed:", error);
        }
    };


The function perform correctly but the user session keep in the database.

If you're using prisma to handle the session store, you'll need to explicitly remove the session data from your database when you log out inside the req.session.destroy function
